# Eclipse will not install app targeting SDK version 30

Tags: eclipse, apk, target

I am updating an app but it now needs to target at least API 30. When I try to install (unsing eclipse) I get the following error....
"Failed parse during installPackageLI: Targeting R+ (version 30 and above) requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary"
I an not trying to export a signed APK - just to install a debug version.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now. Android Studio is the only supported IDE.

Comment: Yes I know its not supported but is there no workaround? Its a very old app and I am just trying to do a little update. Learning to use Studio for such a small thing seems a huge task.